# What type of math classes are good to take for computer science majors?

Tags: education

I am an undergraduate computer science student at Cal Poly (SLO) and I have some flexibility in which math courses I can take, but I don't know which math courses would be most beneficial. I have already taken a statistics/probability course and Calculus 3. My options are pretty flexible for a Mathematics/Statistics elective. What type of math is most useful to know for the field of computer science? I still don't know what type of career I would like, so general answers are okay; or some specific classes for specific career paths would be great too. Thanks!

Comment: There have been similar questions at math.stackexchange.com at least, probably elsewhere. A definite answer is almost impossible to give, CSc is *very* broad, the math you'd need for, say, software engineering research is very different from what you'd need for algorithm design, which in turn has little in common with what is required for network (or computer system) modelling.

Comment: Can't go wrong with linear algebra. Plenty of stuff expressible in systems of linear equations that want solving. Also, the algebra part of linear algebra is useful to get a taste for abstract properties of operations and algebraic structures. Other than that, vonbrand is right saying that questions like this should be easy to find on CS.

Comment: For something somewhat comprehensive, check out [this question](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/3457/math-for-tcs-major) plus the links presented in the answers.

Answer (score 0):

Discrete maths will be the first priority.

then number theory.

Comment: Number theory? I understand that you would want to do that for cryptography and some complexity theory, but other than that, I can't think of much to do with number theory in CS.

Comment: @G.Bach I agree. Unless you're interested in cryptography, you probably won't need any number theory at all. (Or, if you do, it'll be the Chinese remainder theorem or something similarly basic, which you can pick up from Wikipedia.)